# Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

An incoming freshman Mark believes that he has a 25% chance of earning a GPA in the 3.5 to 4 range, a 35% chance of graduating with a 3.0 to 3.5 GPA and 40% chance of finishing with a GPA less than 3.0. Also, Mark has an 8/10 chance of getting into med school if his GPA is above a 3.5, a 5/10 chance if his GPA is between 3 and 3.5 and a 1/10 chance if its below 3. Based on these estimates what is the probability that Mark gets into med school?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The law of total probability says that $Pr(A)=\sum_{n} Pr(B_n)Pr(A|B_n)$ as long as the $B_n$ are disjoint and the union of all the $B_n$ is the entire sample space. Applying that to this problem gives:

$$Pr(Med\, School)=Pr(GPA>3.5)*Pr(Med\, School|GPA>3.5)+Pr(3.0<GPA<3.5)Pr(Med\, School|3.0<GPA<3.5)+Pr(GPA<3.0)Pr(Med\, School|GPA<3.0)$$